# Blender render resolution change after remdering image!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, resolution

I need to render a image in blender in 1600x720 and i set the resolution to 1600x720 but after render the image the resolution changes to 3000x1440.
(I'm rendering in cycles)

Comment: Is the percentage set to 100%?

Comment: are you using the "compositing" nodes?